# Convert rails STI type param to the actual class constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, sti, uninitialized-constant

I am rails newbie. I create STI with the following `class User` and its `class Teacher < User` subclasses. It thrown an error when I fill in the user form.

## NameError at /users

> uninitialized constant User::teacher

### app/controllers/users_controller.rb, line 29

```rb
   24     end
   25   
   26     # POST /users
   27     def create 
   28       byebug 
>  29       @user = User.new(user_params) 
   30       authorize @user    
   31       if @user.save
   32         render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user, serializer: UserSerializer
   33       else
   34         render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

### App backtrace

- app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `create'

### Full backtrace

```
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:206:in    `compute_type'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:233:in `find_sti_class'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:263:in `subclass_from_attributes'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:56:in `new'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `create'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in    `send_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:196:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in    process_action'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in    `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
```

I guess I am missing the part of constantize the string param to actual class constant. How to do it?

Please guide. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a type in database also by looking at `uninitialized constant User::teacher` it seems you are using a lower version somewhere. It should be `User::Teacher`

Comment: rails -v 6.0.1 and ruby -v 2.6.5. `User::Teacher` does it mean i have to namespace model and controller? and also  `config.load_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/users"`

Comment: `resources :teachers, controller: 'users', type: 'Teacher'` in routes. And  `scope :teachers, -> { where(role: 'Teacher') }` in user model

Answer (score 0):

as Paula Fidalgo said to make sure you have type column as a string in User model schema

after that, you can create new entries in the User model as below

```
Teacher.create(user_params)

User.create(type: 'Teacher')
```

both are same.